# getActivity() via Android Service

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

How can I get current/running Activity from Android Service? I am working on Screen Locker and I need to getActivity() and getWindow() in order to getDecorView() to make navigation bar hidden. If anyone knows better solution, please comment. Thanks!

Comment: getActivity(). Your question is self-answered. Did you get any problems with it ?

Comment: Method getActivity() is not accessable in a class that extends Service

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get a reference to the Activity as far as I know.
A classic aproach to communicate between a Service and an Activity is by using a BroadcastReceiver.

Here is an Example:

on your Activity you can create a Inner class that extends BroadcastReceiver:

```
private class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

            if (arg1.hasExtra(Constants.SOME_ACTION)) {
                //DO YOUR THING
            }
        }

    }
```

Don't forget to register it on onCreate:

```
serviceReceiver = new ServiceReceiver();
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(Constants.SERVICE_RECEIVER);
registerReceiver(serviceReceiver, intentFilter);
```

and to unRegister it on onPause()

```
 if (serviceReceiver != null)
            unregisterReceiver(serviceReceiver);
```

Then from your Service you can send a Broadcast on an Event, something like this:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setAction(Constants.SERVICE_RECEIVER);
                            intent.putExtra(Constants.SOME_ACTION, true);
                            sendBroadcast(intent);
```

This way your Activity can react to Events on your Service.

Comment: I have just read something about BroadcasstReceivers, but how can I getActivity() using it?

Comment: Thank you very much, but the problem is that I dont have an activity. I am building touch blocker that covers screen with custom view and blocks navigation buttons. I have completed the screen cover task so all that is left is blocking navigation buttons and possibli hiding the status bar. My service needs to be able to listen to user inpit on top of every activity. There are some similar apps on google play store so you can check them out to see what am I talking about. Thanks again for your time.